# How do I fix a Unity error that says that a file has been compiled by a more recent version of Java?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, compilation

I'm trying to build an app in Unity with the Niantic Lightship ARDK, and when I try to build, I get numerous errors, as follows:

**Error 1**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Exception in thread "main" 

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
Niantic.ARDK.AR.WayspotAnchors.Editor._RemoteAuthoringPresenceManager:OnBuild (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/ARDK/Editor/RemoteContent/_Re
```

**Error 2**

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to update Android SDK package list.
C:\Users\nicol\Documents\Coding\Android_Stuff\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat --list

Environment Variables:
RlsSvcPort = 22112
USERDOMAIN = LAPTOP-Q6VE2AHH
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
TMP = C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 5000
OS = Windows_NT
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_1732_VDPTYNALVSTRAPDP
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = AMD64 Family 25 Model 80 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\nicol
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.16f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
ComSpec = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
SystemRoot = C:\WINDOWS
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 16
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer
HOMEDRIVE = C:
TEMP = C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp
Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git LFS;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022a\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\nicol\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;
ACSvcPort = 17532
USERNAME = nicol
COMPUTERNAME = LAPTOP-Q6VE2AHH
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SystemDrive = C:
windir = C:\WINDOWS
ACSetupSvcPort = 23210
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default
HOMEPATH = \Users\nicol
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
APPDATA = C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Roaming
OneDrive = C:\Users\nicol\OneDrive
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 25
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
NVIDIAWHITELISTED = 0x01
SESSIONNAME = Console
GIT_LFS_PATH = C:\Program Files\Git LFS
LOGONSERVER = \\LAPTOP-Q6VE2AHH
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local
VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE = 1
SHIM_MCCOMPAT = 0x810000001
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = LAPTOP-Q6VE2AHH
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Exception in thread "main" 
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunAndroidSdkTool (System.String toolName, System.String arguments, System.Boolean updateCommand, System.String errorMsg, System.String toolsDir, System.String[] warningsToIgnore) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.ListComponentsVersions () (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager.UpdatePackagesList () (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager.HighestVersionInstalled (UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager+Component tool) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKToolsDetector.GetVersion () (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector.Detect (System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.ProgressHandler onProgress) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.EnsureSDKComponentVersion (System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector detector) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions)
Niantic.ARDK.AR.WayspotAnchors.Editor._RemoteAuthoringPresenceManager:OnBuild(BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/ARDK/Editor/RemoteContent/_RemoteAutho
```

**Error 3**

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <11d97693183d4a6bb35c29ae7882c66b>:0 
  at Niantic.ARDK.AR.WayspotAnchors.Editor._RemoteAuthoringPresenceManager.OnBuild (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00039] in C:\Users\nicol\Documents\Unity Projects\advanced-game-studio\bruh\Assets\ARDK\Editor\RemoteContent\_RemoteAuthoringPresenceManager.cs:170 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Action`1[UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions].invoke_void_T(UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00072] in <11d97693183d4a6bb35c29ae7882c66b>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I've tried pretty much everything I can find online. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Unity and my JRE, updating the JRE to 11 but Unity prompts that I can only use 8, using both the Unity default and my own path for Android SDK Tools. I've tried changing my build settings around and I've installed Android Studio to try and continue to work with different build-tools and the works. None of these attempts have been successful.

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler (javac) writes the version of the Java byte code in the compiled class files. If the JVM doesn't know the version it can't support it, so it refuses to load the class.

You have to use an older version of javac or tell a newer javac to generate compatible (old) byte code.

Comment: How can I do that? I've tried uninstalling my current version of Java and installing an older version, but that hasn't worked.